# UDP multicast in Windows Azure cloud service

Tags: azure, multicast, azure-web-roles, azure-worker-roles

Is there any support for multicast UDP within a Windows Azure cloud service? I've set up internal endpoints for the UDP protocol in my roles, but my guess is that they're only opened for the IP addresses assigned to the web/worker roles in my cloud service, and that the roles don't listen on 224.0.0.0 - 239.255.255.255.

I can imagine a workaround for my situation, based on unicast and additional configuration, but by default we run on multicast, so it would be lovely.

Thanks!

Comment: There is a possible solution that is described here: https://blog.pythian.com/network-multicast-support-azure/. Also since November 2021 there is a cloudSwXtch plugin (paid plugin) that allegedly does the same thing (https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/swxtchiollc1614108926893.sdmc-1_1?tab=Overview).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Azure does not support Multicast UDP currently.  Due to security concerns they have decided to support UDP, but not multicast.  Based on a recent comment by Corey Sanders on the [my great windows azure idea site](http://www.mygreatwindowsazureidea.com/forums/169386-cloud-services-web-and-worker-role-/suggestions/547215-multicast-support) they do not plan on implementing this in the near future.